# Concatenate strings in 2 different lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, cartesian-product

I need to **concatenate** 2 different lists of strings in python.

for example:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['D', 'E']
```

I want to obtain

```
list3 = ['AD', 'AE', 'BD', 'BE', 'CD', 'CE']
```

I've tried:

```
list3 = zip(list1,list2)
```

And it returns

```
list3 = [('A','D'), ('B','E')]
```

I've also tried:

`list(itertools.product(list1, list2))`

But it returns

> [('A','D'),('A','E'),...,('C','E')] and not ['AD', 'AE', 'BD', 'BE',
>   'CD', 'CE']

Any idea? THX

Comment: It looks like you want the `itertools.product` ("cartesian product") of the lists

Comment: Try this list3 = [i+j for i in list1 for j in list2]

Answer (score 5):

This should help:

```
import itertools

list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['D', 'E']
list(map("".join, itertools.product(list1, list2)))
# ['AD', 'AE', 'BD', 'BE', 'CD', 'CE']
```

Also, can be solved with a list comprehension.

```
["".join(i) for i in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the Cartesian product or employ 2 loops

```
>>> list1 = ['A','B','C']
>>> list2 = ['D', 'E']
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
[('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E')]
>>> [(i, j) for i in list1 for j in list2]
[('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E')]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about two for loops?

pseudocode below

```
for item in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
         item = item + item2
```