# Concatenating Strings: "Multiplication" of two list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, cartesian-product

For list of strings,
define the multiplication operation in as concatenating here:

```
l1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
l2 = ['11', '22']
l3 = l1 op l2
```

Expected output:

```
l3 = ['aa11', 'aa22', 'bb11', 'bb22', 'cc11', 'cc22']
```

Simply we can use

```
for l in l1:
    for ll in l2:
        l3.append(l+ll)
```

But I'd be grateful to hear a pythonic solution.

Comment: What is "not pythonic" here? Do you mean "code that is hardly to understand = pythonic"? Think of developers who will support your code. They will be glad to have this logic exactly in such form (nested loops) as your have done. The solution of @jedwards is also good from the point of view of maintainability and understanding.

Comment: What you implemented *is not* a dot product.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Correct. It should be phrased as multilication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concatenate strings in 2 different lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885876/concatenate-strings-in-2-different-lists-in-python)

Comment: is op the + operation or is op a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

l1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
l2 = ['11', '22']

l3 = [x+y for (x,y) in product(l1,l2)]

print(l3)
```

But it's effectively the same thing as what you're doing (provided you fix the typo :P)

Answer (score 2):

```
l3 = [a+b for a in l1 for b in l2]
```