# How to combine two lists together into a list of tuples using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I know that this doesn't have to be done by doing recursion. I want to combine two lists such as `x = [0, 1]` and `y = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and create a function that puts them in a list of tuples such as: `[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')]`.

I know only how to do this for the first index of list x and struggling to figure out how to move on to further indexes. The output for the function below is: `[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c')]`.

```
def combine(x, y, idx=0):
    if idx < len(y):
        return [(x[idx], y[idx])] + combine(x, y[1:])
    else:
        return []
```

I don't know how to get to get the list x to move onto further indexes. I think I may need to call all_pairs(list1, list2, index+1 instead of slicing the list. Do I need to have the function call itself twice? This may seem elementary but for whatever reason I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product of two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192855/cartesian-product-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @kaya3 OP specifically asks for a *recursive* solution which none of the answers to that question are.

Comment: @Nick OP specifically says *"I know that this doesn't have to be done by doing recursion"* which seems to me to be the opposite to "this has to be done using recursion".

Comment: @kaya3 The question title asks for a recursive solution; the body just gives the message that OP understands that the problem can be solved using methods other than recursion.

Comment: @Nick I see your point. There are still other questions with recursive answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534085/12299000) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102114/12299000), although those are not specific to the case of two lists.

Comment: @kaya3 you're right, there's an answer there which is a recursive solution for lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
from itertools import product
a = list(product(x,y))
a
```

or just list comprehension as below

```
[(a,b) for a in x for b in y]
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')]
```