# Make ordered pairs from two lists in Python

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose I have two lists: `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [3, 4, 5]`.

What is the Python way of making tuples `(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)`?

Comment: Have you tried *anything at all*? `for i in a: for j in b: ...`???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product of two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192855/cartesian-product-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @JanezKuhar Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the lists are bigger and u don't want to manually add all the for steps in a list comprehension u can use `itertools`, for example:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]

result = list(product(a, b))
print(result)
>>> [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

gives you `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

Check [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which is the exact equivalent code of  the answer provided by @orangecat but it returns as iterator.

So if you want list of these you can just do the following:

```
  output = list(itertools.product(a, b))
```